# GET request to REST API crashes server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

This is my first time building a REST API With Node.js, Express, & MongoDB. The DB (named API) has two collections (Articles and Sources) with over 100k documents in the Articles collection. Every time I send  this GET request `http://localhost:3000/Articles/results?limit=10` to the Articles collection, postman hangs then the server crashes. On a good note, if I send a get request with the just the `_id` it returns the document. Below is my code

```
require('dotenv').config()

const express = require('express') 
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true })
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', (error) => console.error(error))
db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Database'))

app.use(express.json())

const articlesRouter = require('./routes/articles')
app.use('/articles', articlesRouter)

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server Started'))
```

Routes

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Article = require('../models/articles')

//Getting All Articles
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const articles = await Article.find()
      res.json(articles)
  } catch (err){
    res.status(400).json({message: err.message})
  }
})

//Getting One Article
router.get('/:id', getArticle, (req, res) => {
  res.json(res.article)

})

async function getArticle(req, res, next) {
  let article
  try{
    article = await Article.findById(req.params.id)
    if (article == null) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Cannot find article'})
    }
  } catch(err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
  }

  res.article = article
  next() 
}

module.exports = router
```

Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

var articlesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: String, content: String, description: String, publishedAt: Date, source_id: String, summarization: String, title: String, url: String, urlToImage: String}, { collection: 'Articles'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Articles', articlesSchema);
```

The error that occurs when the server crashes is lengthy, below is a snippet of it

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x10007e891 node::Abort() [/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.8.0/bin/node]
 2: 0x10007e9c0 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.8.0/bin/node]
 3: 0x10017e6ab v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.8.0/bin/node]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your query param `limit` is not used to limit your find, thus your are trying to find all your 100K articles, which is causing your heap to overflow. In routes on line 8, try:

```
const articles = await Article.find({}, null, {limit: parseInt(req.query.limit, 10)})
```

An idea going forward might also be to validate the `req.query.limit` before using it directly for the call to mongoose, so you don't accidentally crash the node app by passing in very high values or simply forgetting to add the limit as a query param in your get request.

Comment: And, the server should make absolutely sure the limit is sanitized to a reasonable value in case a non-reasonable value is passed in.

Comment: @jfriend00 Absolutely right. I added that bit just as you added your comment I believe :)

Comment: I made the changes, sent this GET request ```http://localhost:3000/Articles?limit=10``` and got this response ```"message": "Failed to parse: { find: \"Articles\", filter: {}, projection: {}, limit: \"10\", returnKey: false, showRecordId: false, lsid: { id: UUID(\"22d332f8-788a-4737-9712-cb8515241f1d\") }, $db: \"API\" }. 'limit' field must be numeric."```

Comment: My bad. The limit needs to be parsed to a number. Check the updated one.